# ColdFusion 11 and Java 8u25 and -XX:+UseStringDeduplication don't want to work

Tags: java, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion 11 update 2 server and I wanted to try out new Java UseStringDeDuplication

**Setting that does work**

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -XX:+UseG1GC 
-Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Duser.language=en 
-Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib 
-Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true
-Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random
```

**Setting that does not work**

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication 
-Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.home={application.home} -Duser.language=en
-Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home} -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/lib 
-Dorg.apache.coyote.USE_CUSTOM_STATUS_MSG_IN_HEADER=true
-Dcoldfusion.jsafe.defaultalgo=FIPS186Random
```

**Error Message when starting CF service**

> Nov 27, 2014 12:42:35 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks SEVERE: The web application [/] created a
>   ThreadLocal with key of type [coldfusion.util.DateUtils$1] (value
>   [coldfusion.util.DateUtils$1@3067104]) and a value of type
>   [java.util.GregorianCalendar] (value
>   [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1417077698336,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=false,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=48,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=27,DAY_OF_YEAR=331,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=41,SECOND=38,MILLISECOND=336,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak. Nov 27, 2014 12:42:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
>   INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8500"] Nov 27, 2014 12:42:35
>   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8014"]

I am wondering if some additional settings need to be changed

Comment: Just for the sake of people trying to analyse those two config strings, I have confirmed the only difference is the latter has `XX:+UseStringDeduplication`.

Comment: Sounds like this should be addressed to the ColdFusion people as we all most likely will be unable to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the underlying issue you are trying to solve. I would bet (as you can see) that ColdFusion doesn't support this as there are secondary effects with (probably) date time parsing.

Comment: this does not answer the question, please use comments and/or chat to get more information or comment answer.

Comment: Yeah, Hrvoje it does answer the question. The answer *to the question that was asked* is that CF won't run with that switch set. The OP can now ask a situation-specific question as to what they are trying to achieve over on StackOverflow, and we can address it from there. DOn't simply blurt out "doesn't answer the question" because it contains another question. It's *completely legit* to pose a different question in an answer. Perhaps stick to subjects you know about (CF ain't one of them) before offering your editorial "insight".

Comment: I am trying to see if there is any performance benefit to using this setting. In particular, I have an app that sometimes copies large strings and I was looking to see if I got a performance improvment

Answer (score 2):

This error is just an additional logging with no behavioural impact. This stack trace is not showing the exact message, if ColdFusion is not starting. To identify the exact error message, try the following:-

1. Stop ColdFusion service, if already running.
2. Launch Command prompt as Administrator.
3. Browse to cf_root\cfusion\bin and run the following command **coldfusion -start console**.
4. Try to access the ColdFusion Admin, once the services are started.

In case it gives an error message, please share the same.

Comment: I am on MacOS. I tried running it with `./coldfusion start console` but it didn't change anything

Comment: Can you share the stack trace from terminal?